# Unable to display the greater symbol at the specific location in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am curently having trouble displaying the the greater sign on my td element in my angular 4 application. I need to dislay the td element only at the place as seen in the screenshot.
It displays correctly the first time but when I edit any of the max values, the td with the greater than sign is replaced in that area. How do I prevent this from happening. I need to limit the greater than sign only at the location as seen in the screenshot.

I tried the following conditions for e.g . Here I mean is that do not display the greater than sign if it is not the last element in the array

```
html



<td colspan="2" *ngIf="!item.maxSize && $last"  class="text-right">  &gt;
          <click-input  contenteditable="true">
              <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
          </click-input>
      </td>
```

Original main html code

[image]

```
       <td *ngIf="!!item.maxSize">
        <click-input  contenteditable="true">
            <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"  required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
        </click-input>
      </td>

      <td *ngIf="!!item.maxSize">
          <click-input  contenteditable="true">
              <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
          </click-input>
      </td>  


     <td colspan="2" *ngIf="!item.maxSize"  class="text-right">  &gt;
          <click-input  contenteditable="true">
              <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
          </click-input>
      </td>     



      <td class="text-right">
        <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
            <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[0]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
        </click-input>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">
          <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
              <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[1]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
          </click-input>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

After making the the first max input field , the screen looks like below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed . I used let last = last;

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items; let last = last;">
            <td *ngIf="!last">
                <click-input contenteditable="true">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"  required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                </click-input>
              </td>

              <td *ngIf="!last">
                  <click-input contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                  </click-input>
              </td>  
             <td  colspan="2" *ngIf="last"  class="text-right">  <span>&gt;</span>
                  <click-input contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                  </click-input>
              </td>     
              <td class="text-right">
                <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[0]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
                </click-input>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right">
                  <click-input [classNames]="['percentage']" contenteditable="true">
                      <input [(ngModel)]="item.values[1]"  numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" required min="0" max="999999999999999">
                  </click-input>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try wrapping it in a span and applying a CSS class if you need to:

```
<td colspan="2" *ngIf="!item.maxSize"  class="text-right">
   <span>&gt;</span>
   <click-input  contenteditable="true">
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
   </click-input>
</td>
```

You might also need to provide more details. I'm kind of unsure if this is what you are trying to do. What does the "click-input" component do (I'm assuming it triggers a state change from text to the input editor?)

Comment: Could you give me an example of the css class ?

Comment: When the user clicks any of the max input boxes and leaves it empty , the td with the greater sizn is getting rendered

Comment: Updated the post on how it looks

Comment: First question: did you intend to use "!!item.maxSize" in the top 2 <td> elements? Did you mean to use "!!item.minSize" on the first one?

Comment: Can you also include the whole table in your example? Hard to see if there is some formatting going on that is forcing your columns to the right (which is what is seems like it's doing).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell, as it's not really clear what's causign the sign to disappear.

You could try setting the ">" sign in CSS as a work around (assuming `click-input` is rendered in the dom

**css**

```
click-input.addSign::before
{
    content: ">";
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**html**

```
<click-input class="addSign"  contenteditable="true">
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
  </click-input>
```